# Connecting an editButtonItem to a UITableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` which adds a `UITableView` and a `UIToolbar` to its view.  Unfortunately I can not use a `UITableViewController` in this instance.

I have added the view controller's `editButtonItem` to the toolbar. I need to replicate the default behavior of the edit button on a `UITableViewController` - the edit button should be tied to the tableView and switch it in/out of edit mode.

I have overridden the `UIViewController`'s `setEditing` to include the line:

```
[_tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
```

and this works for the most part - the table view successfully enters and exits edit mode when the `editButtonItem` is used.

However, there is at least one issue. On a `UITableViewController`, the edit button switches to 'done' when a the user slides across a row in the table. 'Done' then returns that row to it's non-editing version. Also, touching outside the row returns it to view mode, and reverts the edit button to 'Done'.

My questions:

1. How can I replicate this behavior, such that the Edit button changes state when an individual row enters/exits edit mode?
2. What other behaviors of the `UITableViewController`'s `editButtonItem` might I need to replicate?

Comment: Everywhere in this post that you said UIView, you meant UIViewController. Big difference.

Comment: Yes, in some places - thanks, I've updated. The tableview and toolbar are subviews of the view controller's view, but the editButtonItem certainly belongs to the controller. Please feel free to edit the question in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have such a case in my own app. I implemented the following table view delegate methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
}
```